# Impromptu - prompt will not close

Tags: javascript, function, impromptu

I am trying Impromptu in my javascript and for some reason it will load fine, all the functionality I apply within works but calling a close or using the 'x' in the upper right will not close the prompt. The opacity of the overlay lightens slightly but the prompt is model and I can continue to interact with it but not the underlying page.

I have gone back to basics and I am using this function;

```
$Kurve.prototype.tooltip = function(){
    $.prompt('Hello World',{ opacity: 0.1 });
}
```

It is being called a part of a JQPlot chart;

```
$l_jqPlotArg.highlighter.tooltipContentEditor = $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', this.tooltip]);
```

Any help appreciated and if you need more info I will do my best to supply it...also, if you have a better suggestion on an overlaying prompt (with good appearance) that can handle a JSON please don't hesitate to tell me!

I have asked th

Thanks
C

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out...the click listener was fine but I had to move the handler to a var inside the chart function. All is well :)